# I have implemented simple bash like shell using c program but its not working as expected

Tags: c, multiprocessing, fork

I have created one bash like program but when i tried to execute it's working fine at 1st time only then after it's not working as expected

The last executed output is repeatedly showing instead of asking new input

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<unistd.h>
 #include<string.h>
 #include<sys/wait.h>

 char full_cmd[20];

 void command_source(char *cmd)
 {

    FILE *fp;
    char output[20];
    char *token;
    token = strtok(cmd," ");
    strcpy(full_cmd,"which ");
    strcat(full_cmd,token);
    fp = popen(full_cmd,"r");
    while (fgets(output, 20, fp) != NULL) {
            strcpy(full_cmd,output);
    }
    full_cmd[strlen(full_cmd)-1] = '\0';

    token = strtok(NULL," ");
    while (token != NULL)
    {
            strcat(full_cmd,token);
            token = strtok(NULL," ");
    }

  }

  void get_input(char input[10])
  { 
    printf("Enter the command:");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",input);
  }

  int launch_shell(char *buff[50],int status)
  {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if( pid == 0 )
    {
            execv(buff[0],buff);
    }
    else if (pid > 0)
    {
            pid_t wpid = waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
    }
    else
            return 0;
    return 1;
  }

  int main()
  {
    char *buff[50];
    int status;
    char input[10];
    int count=0,ret=1;
    while(ret == 1)
    {
            get_input(input);
            command_source(input);
            strcpy(buff[0],full_cmd);
            buff[1] = NULL;
            int ret = launch_shell(buff,status);
    }
  }
```

Expected:

```
Enter the command:ls 
server.c server
Enter the command:ls -l
server.c
server
```

Actual results:

```
Enter the command:ls
server  server.c
server  server.c
server  server.c
server  server.c
server  server.c
server  server.c
server  server.c
server  server.c
server  server.c
server  server.c
server  server.c
server  server.c
server  server.c
server  server.c
...
```

Please help me guys to find out the issue in this. I spend whole day to slove this. But I couldn't.

Comment: You are ignoring the return value of scanf() at your own risk. Consider not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the statement

```
scanf("%[^\n]s",input);
```

you are saying "read until there's a newline". So after the first input, the newline character is left in the input stream which prevents stops subsequent input reading immediately. Better idea would be to use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()`.

You could pass the size argument to `get_input` function such as:

```
  void get_input(char input[10], size_t size)
  { 
    printf("Enter the command:");
    if (fgets(input, size, stdin) != NULL) {
        char *p = strchr(input, '\n');
        if (p) *p = '\0';
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "fgets failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
  }
```

and call it:

```
    get_input(input, sizeof input);
```

You also have a number of issues:

1.

```
strcpy(buff[0],full_cmd);
```

isn't correcr because `buff[0]` isn't initialized. You can instead just assign:

```
buff[0] = full_cmd;
```

2. You can't have arguments to command in your current approach. Because *each* of the arguments and command need to be passed as different parameters of the array `buff` to `execv`.

   So you need to split the input based on whitespace and put them into the array `buff` before calling `launch_shell`.  For example, "ls -l" would be a single argument to `execv` (passed via `buff[0]`). But that's not what `execv` accepts. You need to put "ls" into `buff[0]` and "-l" into `buff[1]` and NULL into `buff[2]` and then call `execv`.

Comment: But even for simple "ls" also i am getting this same issue

Comment: That's becase of the noted issue noted first: there's a newline (`\n`) character which immediately stops scanf from reading further input.

Comment: Just updated to show how to use `fgets` for input reading. But as already noted, you still need to split the args in order to exec commands with arguments.